# In R: Repeat each raw of a data frame a desired number of times (that could be different for every row)

Tags: r, repeat

I have my own solution tp my problem , but it involves looping and is relatively slow. Any way to do it faster in R - using some more advanced packages?
Thank you!

```
# My data frame:
d <- data.frame(ID=1:10,a = 1:10,b = 5:14)
# Desired number of repeats for each row:
freq = c(2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,6)
# i.e., Raw 1 of d should be repeated 2 times
# Raw 10 of d should be repeated 6 times.

# My current solution - looping through unique values of freq:
d.long<-NULL
myrepeats=unique(freq)
for(i in myrepeats){
  onecount<-d[freq==i,]
  for(ii in 2:i){
    temp<-d[freq==i,]
    onecount<-rbind(onecount,temp)
  }
  d.long<-rbind(d.long,onecount)
}
d.long<-d.long[order(d.long$ID),]
(d.long)
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use repeated indices:

```
d.long <- d[rep(1:nrow(d), times=freq),]
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot - it's really fast and elegant!